# Checking third party extension license timeout date?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license, extensions

I have a few third party extensions for ArcMap installed. In Advanced Settings Utility I have the "Starting 15 days prior... show warning..." checked ON.

I do not currently see a warning message when I start ArcMap.

I would like to be able to find the timeout date *before* I get within 15 days of it.

Comment: What extensions? Third party extensions are not licensed the same way as Esri extensions so won't show up in that list.  There may be other ways to do it, but we can't help without knowing which extension.